# C#: Should I use "if" instead of "while" when a Reader has only one element?

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement

Look at this:

```
myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (myReader.HasRows)
{
    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        info = myReader.GetString("info");
        ...
    }
 }
.....
```

Well, I don´t know why, but when I compile it and use it in another PC, it explodes because of the **while**. But If I do:

```
myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (myReader.HasRows)
{
    if (myReader.Read())    <------------------- NOTICE THE IF
    {
        info = myReader.GetString("info");
        ...
    }
 }
.....
```

... will work. Notice that I know that I will have **only one element** every time, because of the logic of the program.

It is OK to do this? It looks horrible and maybe is not a good practice (**?**). I´m asking for your orientation.

**EDIT**:
Will post some more code, because could help in finding my errors:

```
 while (myReader.Read())
 {
    info = myReader.GetString("info");
    ...


     /**
      * Write the relevant info in the LOGS
      */
      connection.Close();     <----------   :S  
      connection.Open();      <---------- if I don´t do this I got some problems with the connection!!!!
      string queryLog = "INSERT INTO ....;
      MySqlCommand cmdLog = new MySqlCommand(queryLog, connection);
      cmdLog.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```

Comment: It looks like there is an underlying problem that you should probably understand rather than just avoiding it as you have. What does explode mean? Is an exception thrown? What exception?

Comment: Is an exception -I do not have at hand right now- but is about the connections. I edited the post to add some code about it.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it, but I don't think that the while loop should blow up either -- I would want to know for certain what was really causing the problem, so that I know the bug is really dead.  Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @Kani I'd suggest you post your entire method (all code where you open this connection and run your reader and logging command) as another question, it looks like it could do with refactoring.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Thank you. I will post, in another questions, some code to specify the problem. @ ALL: Thank you. I received many good answers. But still in an inner **struggle** with the @ Eric J  one. Maybe using **while** is more flexible in terms of expansion of the code. Nevertheless, I will use Adams´solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I do this whenever I am expecting just ***one row***, nothing wrong with it.

If I'm expecting a single value, I use `ExecuteScalar` instead. This will simply return the value held in the first column of the first row of the resultset returned, usally the set only has one column and one row, so you don't tend to notice this.

Also I tend not to bother with `if (myReader.HasRows)` as `if (myReader.Read())` covers this.

I have no idea why the `while` causes you issues... I'm just offering my opinion on using the `if` over the `while` if you aren't expecting multiple rows.

Comment: Interesting.  Until just now, I did not realize ExecuteScalar could return a string.  I always thought of a scalar as a number because it is generally used that way in physics & math, and ExecuteScalar is most often used to return a count.

Comment: @EricJ. Yeah the naming of the method isn't entirely fantastic, but personally I read scalar as a "single value" anyway, so I've never considered your view point until now :-)

Comment: It's consistent with the perl definition of "scalar", which I understand to mean "single element" as opposed to a list.

Comment: @EricJ.: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_%28computing%29. It doesn't have any references, and is spare on the details, but I've often seen "scalar" used in the way the article describes.

Comment: @ruakh It's an historical thing. Strictly strings aren't scalar because we can't put "apple" and "elephant" on a single meaningful scale hence the name - like we can with 3 and 57.23. But lots of cases in computing where scalars are differentiated from composite types, the important characteristics to the matter in hand are indeed shared by "apple" and "elephant", so they got considered "scalar" too. (At another level they'd also not be considered scalar because they're internally composites containing variable numbers of characters along with size information).

Answer (score 3):

I think the use of `if` makes it clear to the readers of your code that you expect precisely one item. You can add an assert after the end to catch logical errors, like this:

```
if (myReader.Read())  {
    info = myReader.GetString("info");
    ...
}
Debug.Assert(!myReader.Read(), "Reader has more elements than expected.");
```

Answer (score 2):

Without using `while`, you cannot detect an unexpected condition the the reader has more elements than you think it should have.  Systems change over time, and assumptions like "the reader will only ever have one element" tend to become incorrect as the system evolves.

If it's important to the function of the system, or of the function of the code you're writing that has that assumption baked in, I would still use a `while` and include some debug build only code that asserts that you really only received one element.

Comment: Good point, and doesn't really hurt to use While instead of If. No performance issue that I'm aware in this area

Comment: Thank you. I believe that you are right that the system could change. I will talk with me colleges to see is the requirements won´t change, **ever**

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed use `if`, but you also should be able to use `while` in a case like this without an error. Just changing it to `if` will work, but if you do the same thing in a case where you can have more than one row, you're going to get the same error. It's important therefore to look at just why the exception was happening.

Let's examine your code:

```
while (myReader.Read())
 {
    info = myReader.GetString("info");
    ...
```

So far so good.

```
     /**
      * Write the relevant info in the LOGS
      */
      connection.Close();     <----------   :S  
      connection.Open();      <---------- if I don´t do this I got some problems with the connection!!!!
```

Oh uh! You've fixed your "some problems", but did you know what those "some problems" were? It's actually here that you've broken your `while`.

At the point where I said "so far so good", this is what you have happening:

1. You have a connection object. It is "open".
2. You have a data reader object. It is retrieving data from the connection.

Now, by the spec of `IDbCommand.ExecuteReader` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68etdec0.aspx), the connection is in use for that reader. You aren't allowed to do anything with that connection except close it, until you call `Close()` on the reader, either explicitly or through `Dispose()` as would happen if the reader was assigned in a `using` block.

Now, strictly this isn't always true. A given implementation is always allowed to give you more than an interface promises (whether according to the interface signature or according to the documentation). Many implementations will "release" the connection for reuse once `Read()` returns false (the only one I ever implemented did), SQLServer 2005 has a `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` option that allows the same connection to simultaneously support more than one datareader at once (there are downsides). Still, these loosenings of the rules aside, the only thing we can definitely do with our connection right now, is call `Close()`.

For this reason, when you tried to call `cmdLog.ExecuteNonQuery()` you got "some problems" in the form of an error message, because you were attempting to use a connection that was in use for something else.

So, you "fixed" this by doing the only thing you could do with the connection - closing it - and then opening it again. For all intents and purposes, you'd a brand new connection!

Now though, when you loop back to the `while` it calls `myReader.Read()` again. This method reads from the stream of data coming from the connection and either returns false (if there's no more results) or creates a set of fields based on what it reads from that stream.

But it doesn't, because you closed that connection. So it "explodes" with an exception because you're trying to read from a closed connection and that just can't be done.

Now, when you replaced this `while` with an `if` you never came back to the `Read()` operation you'd busted, so the code works again.

But what are you going to do if you ever need to do this with a resultset that has more than one row?

You could use MARS. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx for that. Frankly I'd avoid it unless something gains more than this from it; it has some subtle implications that can be really confusing if you hit them.

You could postpone your next operation until after the readerset is closed. In this case, this would just be a minor saving by taking out the needless `Open()` and `Close()`:

```
using(myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
  while(myReader.Read())
  {
    string info = myReader.GetString("info");
    /* Do stuff */
    using(SqlConnection logConn = new SqlConnection(...))
    {
      logConn.Open();
      string queryLog = "INSERT INTO ....;
      MySqlCommand cmdLog = new MySqlCommand(queryLog, connection);
      cmdLog.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
  }
}
```

Now, it may seem wasteful to have two connections rather than one here. However:

1. Pooling makes creation of connections pretty cheap.
2. We're releasing it back into the pool as soon as we do the `ExecuteNonQuery()`, so if there's a lot of this going on across lots of threads the total number of connections on the go will likely be less than twice the number of threads. On the other hand, if there's only one thread doing this, then there's only one extra connection, so who cares.
3. Closing a connection when it was part-way through providing a datareader may have given it extra clean-up to do before returning to the pool, so you may well be using two connections anyway (I don't know about SQLServer, but I do know that some databases need more work before they can return to the pool in such cases).

In summary, you can't use a connection without reusing it, that's an out-and-out bug. You normally can't have more than one operation on the same connection at a time. Using the `MultipleActiveResultSets` option with SQLServer2005 lets you do that, though it has complications. Generally, if you want to do more than one DB thing at a time, you should use more than one connection.

All that said, you can still use `if` rather than `while`, but do it because it's what makes sense at the time, rather than to fix a bug you don't understand and have it come back some time when `if` isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

Do you dispose your connection and reader properly? Use `Using`, like:

```
using (myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (myReader.HasRows)   
    {   
        while (myReader.Read())   
        {   
            info = myReader.GetString("info");   
            ...   
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should still use the while even if you're expecting only one row then use linq to express the single row expectation when you call it. You can use a coroutine to express this nicely.

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetInfo() 
{
    // make command and reader...
    while(reader.Read() 
    {
        yield return reader.GetString("info");
    }
 }
```

Then the caller should use the Single() method to express the expectation of only a single row.

```
var info = GetInfo().Single();
```

Answer (score -5):

this code you should add the following to get it to return or not return rows

```
  myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  myReader.Read();
  if (myReader.HasRows)
  {     
     while (myReader.Read())
     { 
        info = myReader.GetString("info");
     }
  }
```

Comment: That code isn't that great... you iterate your reader before you start reading so you are always going to miss the first return value. The OP is only interested in one row, so this won't actually suffice.

Comment: I understand that.. I was showing him what he could do.. it's up to him to understand which to use.. reading from his code you can't tell if he's going to return one row or many.. so your down vote is a bit premature..

Comment: The downvote was warranted in my opinion, even with multiple rows you are skipping the first row for every resultset returned - I have never seen this needed in the wild and would be annoying to debug. The OP also does mention that he expects "only one element". You are also showing him code that he already has, so I fail to see what value has been added other than a potential bug.