# While and IF in data reader

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop, datareader

How I will combine the while and if in data reader? I tried this but in `while DR1.Read` it does not gives me all the result

```
if(DR1.Read())
{
while(DR1.Read())
{
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(label);
}
}
else
    MessageBox.Show("No results found")
```

Comment: You have a great answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8566729/1257607) regarding this topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
   if (DR1.HasRows)
   {
      while (DR1.Read())
      {
         flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(label);
      }
   }
   else
        MessageBox.Show("No results found");
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using a bool?

Something like

```
bool read = false;
while (DR1.Read())
{
    read = true;
}
if (!read)
    MessageBox.Show("No results found");
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically:

```
if(DR1.Read())
{
    do
    {
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(label);
    }
    while(DR1.Read())
}
else
    MessageBox.Show("No results found")
```

you can put the while at the end, because the `if(DR1.Read())` already loads the first row if present.